# TomEE embedded container not loading WEB-INF/lib java-mysql-connector

Tags: java, mysql, apache-tomee, tomee-7

Trying to load my `WAR` in TomEE 7 embedded container and connect to MySQL.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
Container container = new Container(configuration);
container.deploy("/", new File("/application.war"));
```

So far so good. Inside my WAR's `WEB-INF/lib` I've got all the necessary libraries including `mysql-connector-java-8.0.8-dmr.jar`.

Then I'm trying to create a connection pool and obtain a connection from within the WAR.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
private BasicDataSource dataSource  = new BasicDataSource();
...
dataSource.getConnection();
```

This is where the error occurs.

```
SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://persistence:3306/Database'

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2144)
    ... 41 more
```

I do not have or want a `resources.xml`. When inspecting the class loader, `driver[className=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver@2236756e]` appears to be registered. The failure occurs in `Class.java` line 348 at `return forName0(name, initialize, loader, caller);`.

Is TomEE embedded ignoring the library in `WEB-INF/lib`? How can I load my driver without placing a global driver in Tomcat's dependencies?

Comment: you could use tomee maven plugin http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-maven-plugin.html and specify libs in configuration like `<libs><lib>mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20</lib></libs>`.  you can also have a src/main/tomee to put the conf files